# Case inside where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to add constraint to where clause

What I do is this

```
and case @CCY when 2 then
         not(s1.Number = '810' and s2.Number = '810')
    end
```

It returns error How to handle this? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error can you mention in your question

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Comment: I want to exclude all rows where s1.number and s2.Number is 810

Comment: but not rows for example  where s1.Number=840 and s2.Number=810. Exclude only those where both s1.Number and s2.Number are 810

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply want to get rows where s1.Number and s2.Number are <> 810 (if @CCY=2):

```
WHERE @CCY <> 2 OR
    NOT ( s1.Number = 810 AND s2.Number = 810 )
```

Comment: No, I want to exclude only those where both s1.Number=810 and s2.Number=810, I don't want to exclude those where for instance s1.Number=810 and s2.Number is any other except 810